# Qemu USB Passthrough iPhone disconnects repeatedly

Tags: libvirt

I've a MacOS Catalina in virtual machine (libvirt/qemu), host machine is Fedora 31. I want to passthrough an iPhone SE for iOS development. When I connect the iPhone I see it in `dmesg`

```
[11680.439777] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[11680.457108] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8, bcdDevice= 8.04
[11680.457116] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[11680.457120] usb 3-1: Product: iPhone
[11680.457124] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[11680.457128] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: XXXXX
```

Then I share it to MacOS VM, it disconnects and its Linux USB connection changes from `usb 3-1` to `usb 3-2`. The connection ID increments with each try to share.

I have followed all recomendations to disable iPhone in udev rules and `gvfs-gphoto2 so Fedora doesn't care of the iPhone when connected.

There is similar question [How do I get Qemu USB Passthrough to work for iPad / iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617634/how-do-i-get-qemu-usb-passthrough-to-work-for-ipad-iphone) but there is no answer.

I have more observations. When I share the iPhone to Windows 10 (running in libvirt VM as well), it works, the USB connection doesn't change. When I share iPod 5 to MacOS, it works.

So the problem is only with the iPhone shared to the MacOS. Has anyone been able to share iPhone to virtualized MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this with

```
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x05ac,productid=0x12ab,guest-reset=false \
```

Comment: Where to add this command, can you explain?

Comment: In my case in bash file i use to start vm, so it's just qemu-system-x86_64 cli arguments. Here is [example](https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM/blob/master/basic.sh)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It should be added to official simple-macos-kvm's docs. Thanks

Comment: -1 This post has no context information. It provides no information about where this cryptic snippet should be placed. The guidelines for this site specifically state that this type of one-line post is considered poor quality.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by following the solution provided in this Stack Overflow post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288689/2961368.

The key takeaway here is that if the current user lacks the necessary access to USB devices on the host system, it's essential to run the application with root privileges. This action enabled me to successfully address the problem.