# Connect iphone via usb to sosumi/qemu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, qemu, kvm

I am struggling to find a way to connect my iPhone to my ubuntu 20.04.

I installed macOS via [sosumi](https://github.com/popey/sosumi-snap) and at launch file, I added this line:

```
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x05ac,productid=0x12a8 \
```

from lsusb I got this:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
```

I also did:

```
sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/001/009
```

Also, I have given access to raw-usb.

Whats is happening is that my ubuntu recognizes the iPhone and tries to connect. I am suspecting that ubuntu is stealing the USB connection from sosumi. Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after 3 hours of searching i was able to find a solution.

I am referencing to two links

- [explaining the reason why it is happening](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/qemu-devel/patch/1545122819-29687-1-git-send-email-agk@godking.net/)
- [other person with same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617634/how-do-i-get-qemu-usb-passthrough-to-work-for-ipad-iphone)

the line that did the trick was this one:

```
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x05ac,productid=0x12a8,guest-reset=false,id=iphone \
```

Comment: i tried in this way. but no luck

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue, I found that adding the following line to your QEMU command and **running QEMU as the root** user can be effective:

```
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x05ac,productid=0x1281
```

In my case, this solution worked. It's worth noting that the problem persisted when I did not execute QEMU as the root user.